# Problem in bookmark updation firefox

Tags: 13.10, firefox, sync, bookmarks

I bookmarked lot of pages and I export them as well into a html file.

The thing is whenever is bookmark a page **can it automatically get updated** or **synced** with the html file.

I use 13.10 and Firefox 30.

Comment: you have to import the bookmarks file, follow this link https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-bookmarks-html-file 

[Note: Your 13.10 will end service at this month. Upgrade into 14.04]

Comment: do you try this https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-bookmarks-html-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in facility to automatically sync your bookmarks at the moment you bookmark a page. The bookmarks are stored (since Firefox 4) in a data base file called `places.sqlite` in your Firefox profile. You could conceivably run a script every couple of minutes that reads the table `moz_bookmarks` in this data base, and outputs an HTML formatted list of bookmarks. 
This aside, you have two options:

1. export your bookmarks manually to a HTML file;
2. have your bookmarks auto-exported at the end of a session, as suggested by @Pabi. There is also an add-on called Bookmark Backup that does that, letting you choose where to store the HTML file.

Comment: bookmark backup add-on works!!

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically export them when you close the browser.
Go to `about:config` and set `browser.bookmarks.autoExportHTML` to true.
Another way would be online not with an HTML file using the Firefox Sync: Settings->Sync.

Comment: `browser.bookmarks.autoExportHTML`  set to true but which is the default location that this is happening?

Comment: There should be a bookmark.html somewhere in `~/.mozilla/firefox/`: `find  ~/.mozilla/firefox/ -name bookmark.html`.